# Add Delete details in Master Detail model - ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, crud, master-detail

I am doing CRUD operations on a Master Detail models Team and TeamMember using modal popup. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoLaynKMOoc) to create Add and Delete buttons in Create action like this:

[image]
This is the code i used to perform this:

TeamController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.TeamMembers.Add(new TeamMember() { TeamMemberId = 1 });
        return PartialView("_AddTeamPartialView", team);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(Team team)
    {
        if (team != null)
        {
            _dbcontext.Team.Add(team);
            _dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

_AddTeamPartialView.cshtml:

```
    @model Team

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_AddTeamPartialView";

}


<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="addTeam" aria-labelledby="addTeamLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Team</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="TeamName" class="control-label">TeamName</label>
                                <input asp-for="TeamName" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="TeamName" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Coach" class="control-label">Coach</label>
                                <input asp-for="Coach" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Coach" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="NumberTeamMembers" class="control-label">NumberTeamMembers</label>
                                <input asp-for="NumberTeamMembers" class="form-control" id="NumberOfTeamMembers" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="NumberTeamMembers" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>

                    <h3>Members</h3>
                    
                    <table class="table table-bordered" id="membersTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>

                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>BirthDate</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>
                                    <button id="addbtnMember" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary visible"
                                            onclick="AddItem(this)">
                                        Add
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody >

                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.TeamMembers.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TeamMembers[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TeamMembers[i].BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.TeamMembers[i].Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        
                                        <button id="btnremove-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                                onclick="DeleteItem(this)" >
                                            Delete
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLastIndex" value="0" />
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="javascript:window.location.reload()">CANCEL</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SAVE</button>
                    </div>
                </form>   
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
@*@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}*@
<script>
    function DeleteItem(btn) {
   
        $(btn).closest('tr').remove();
        document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value = document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value - 1;
        
    }
    function AddItem(btn) {
        var table = document.getElementById('membersTable');
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var rowOuterHtml = rows[rows.length - 1].outerHTML;
        var lastrowIdx = document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value;
        var RowNumber = document.getElementById('NumberOfTeamMembers').value;

        var nextrowIdx = eval(lastrowIdx) + 1;

        
            document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value = nextrowIdx;
            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('_' + lastrowIdx + '_', '_' + nextrowIdx + '_');
            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('[' + lastrowIdx + ']', '[' + nextrowIdx + ']');
            rowOuterHtml = rowOuterHtml.replaceAll('-' + lastrowIdx, '-' + nextrowIdx);

        if (nextrowIdx < RowNumber) {
            var newRow = table.insertRow();
            newRow.innerHTML = rowOuterHtml;    
            
        }                
    }
    
</script>
```

By using this code i can add team members less or egal the number of team members, but the problem is that when i delete one the team members (for example the first team member) during the create operation of a new team, all the team members inserted after the deleted one won't be saved. where is the problem in this code?

Comment: Could you please share your `delete` related `code snippet`?

Comment: it is the function in the script  function DeleteItem(btn)

Comment: Yes that's for removing the item in UI. However, you need to write a method in backend which would delete the item from database.

Comment: It is not saved yet. i save the whole items team and its team members at the same time when i click save button (In Create action)

Comment: Did you mean `TeamMembers` has not saved yet?

Comment: The problem is with line `document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value = document.getElementById('hdnLastIndex').value - 1;` in `DeleteItem` function. Let's say last index is 5 and you delete item at index 2, this code will set last index to 4. This doesn't make sense because an item still exists at index 4.

Comment: But when i delete this line of code i couldn't add rows to table equal to the number of team members input